AWS MSK Private Broker with Public NLB
I am trying to provide accesss to MY MSK in internal Network private VPC AWS. I have created Public NLB and associate the target group. In target group the instance is in halthy state and i can directly telnet to that MSK broker with private IP.
But when i try to telnet to NLB Public IP and Port it says operation timed out. The SG rule is Open.
Create NLB Public and add IP(MSK Broker IP private) as target in target group.
The instance is healthy which is expected.
But can not telnet to NLB IP:port
